Split and cast string in where clause
I have a column size of type string containing 50 or 50-56 in a string.
I would like to return all items where size is 50 or size is between 50 and 56.
What would be the best way to achieve this? Should I simply store in as integers and split on INSERT instead?

If "best" means "easiest and fastest to query", I would use a range:
CREATE TABLE thing (
   pk bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   size_range int4range NOT NULL,
);

CREATE INDEX ON thing USING gist (size_range);

Then add values:
INSERT INTO thing VALUES (1, '[50,50]');
INSERT INTO thing VALUES (2, '[50,56]');

Now you can query:
SELECT id, size_range FROM thing WHERE size_range @> 51;

If you insert enough rows, the index will be used.
